# How to change credentials for SVN repository in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, subversive

I have Eclipse 3.4.2 installed on Windows with subclipse. Another developer added an SVN repository with his credentials and selected 'Save password'. Now every time I do anything with SVN his cached credentials are used. How can I change them to mine?

I have already checked the 'workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.tigris...' folders, and could not find any way to reset those cached credentials.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/PluginFAQ#head-d507c29676491f4419997a76735feb6ef0aa8cf8:

> **Usernames and passwords**
>
> Subclipse does not collect or store username and password credentials when defining a repository. This is because the JavaHL and SVNKit client adapters are intelligent enough to prompt you for this information when they need to -- including when your password has changed.
>
> You can also allow the adapter to cache this information and a common question is how do you delete this cached information so that you can be prompted again? We have an open request to have an API added to JavaHL so that we could provide a UI to do this. Currently, you have to manually delete the cache. The location of the cache varies based on the client adapter used.
>
> JavaHL caches the information in the same location as the command line client -- in the Subversion runtime configuration area. On Windows this is located in %APPDATA%\Subversion\auth. On Linux and OSX it is located in ~/.subversion/auth. Just find and delete the file with the cached information.
>
> SVNKit caches information in the Eclipse keyring. By default this is a file named .keyring that is stored in the root of the Eclipse configuration folder. Both of these values can be overriden with command line options. To clear the cache, you have to delete the file. Eclipse will create a new empty keyring when you restart

Comment: So, in my case I've been using JavaHL, which cashes credential data in the Subversion runtime configuration area. On Windows this was in "C:\Documents and Settings\%USER%\Application Data\Subversion\auth\svn.simple" in one of the files with a long HEX name. Opening them in notepad, locating the one with my colleagues credentials and deleting it solved the problem.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Great answer. To make it easy for other users, on Windows 7 it is under C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth\

Comment: If using SVNKit (instead of JavaHL), it caches information in a file named .keyring under configuration\org.eclipse.core.runtime\ inside Eclipse. Close Eclipse and delete the file. Eclipse will create a new empty keyring when restarted.

Comment: On Windows 7 you find the folder with (paste into explorer address): %APPDATA%\Subversion\auth

Comment: On Linux, I needed to delete: $home/.subversion/auth/svn.simple/*

Comment: for me the .keyring file was in /opt/eclipse/.configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/

Comment: The problem is if we have MORE than one GIT account :-\ SVN always saves credentials with <https://github.com:443>

Answer (score 42):

My wife suggested:

1. Open SVN Repositories View
2. Open Location Properties...
3. Show Credentials For: press [X] button
4. Select user, write password, press [Finish]

and all work!!!

Comment: That appears to be for Subversive, not Subclipse.  Is that right?  Using Subclipse, I see "Properties", not "Location Properties...", and the dialog that appears for that does not contain anything about user, password, or authentication at all.

Comment: open Windows/Preferences, type SVN in the search box, then "configuration location". The folder should contain a config and server files, and a auth subfolder...

Comment: very nice. In my case I had to manually set up the repository location and auth information before selecting maven project import because during import I could not enter any auth information........

Answer (score 24):

Go to `c:\Documents and Settings\[username]\Application Data\subversion\auth\svn.simple`

and delete the hexadecimal file. Normally each file is associated with one repository

Answer (score 14):

It's too simple to change username and password in Eclipse.

Just follow the following steps:

In your Eclipse,

> Goto Window -> Show View -> Other -> (Type as) SVN Repositories -> click that(SVN Repositories) -> Right Click SVN Repositories ->  Location Properties -> General tab change the following details for credentials.,

that's it.

Answer (score 13):

On Mac OS X, go to folder /$HOME (/Users/{user home}/). You will see file '.eclipse_keyring'.
Remove it. All saved credentials will be lost.

Answer (score 12):

On any Windows Version delete the following folder:

> %APPDATA%\Subversion\auth

(You can copy&paste this to RUN/Explorer, and it will resolve the App-Data-Folder for you.)

On Linux and OSX it is located in

> ~/.subversion/auth

Source:
http://www.techcrony.info/2008/03/26/admin/how-to-change-eclipse-svn-password/

Answer (score 8):

On Windows 7, go to C:\Users\%User_Name%\AppData\Roaming\Subversion and remove the auth directory. Just be aware if you are connected to more than 1 SVN server that this will remove the authentication for all of the SVN servers you have configured. If you want to reset just a single server:

Inside the auth directory you should see a folder called svn.simple. Open each of those files with a text editor to determine which one to remove and then remove just that single file.

Answer (score 8):

In windows :

1. Open run type `%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth\svn.simple`
2. This will open `svn.simple` folder
3. you will find a file e.g. Big Alpha Numeric file
4. Delete that file.
5. Restart eclipse.
6. Try to edit file from project and commit it
7. you can see dialog asking userName password

It worked for me.... ;)

Comment: This is a valid solution in Windows 10

Answer (score 7):

Very simple step to follow:
Eclipse: Window ----> Preferences -----> SVN -----> SVN Interface ----->Select SVNKit (pure Java)

Answer (score 5):

I was able unable to locate the `svn.simple` file, but was able to change credentials using the following three steps:

Checkout project from SVN

[image]

Select the repository you need to change the credentials on (note: you will not perform an checkout, but this will bring you to the screen to enter a username/password combination).

[image]

Finally, enter the new username and password credentials:

[image]

It's a bit confusing, because you begin the process of initializing a new project, but you're only resetting the repository credentials.

Answer (score 3):

On any Windows Version follow this path:

`C:\Users\{user_name}\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth\svn.simple`

Then delete the file with hexa decimal code inside this folder and restart your eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

(Windows 7 Eclipse Indigo 3.7)

C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth\svn.simple

Find svn information file and make it writable.
  (they are default readonly)
  (no restart of eclipse required)

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the method I have written below, and it works perfectly for me

in eclipse, follow these simple steps:
File -> Import -> type svn -> project from svn -> next -> Create a new repository location -> Next - > You would see "Secure Storage" below the  Authentication Menu. Click on this button "Secure Storage" . This is the place where we can delete all the password caches. Now once you are here, follow these:

1. Under password tab, click "Clear passwords"
2. Under "contents" tab, go to SVN, select each sub options, and click on "Delete"
3. Restart eclipse

All the stored passwords are now gone, and you can use your new svn password to sync

Comment: Simpler way CTRL + 3 -> Type `Secure Storage`

Answer (score 2):

Delete the .keyring file under the location: configuration\org.eclipse.core.runtime, and after that, you will be invited to prompt your new svn account.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the .keyring file under the location: configuration\org.eclipse.core.runtime, and after that, you will be invited to prompt your new svn account.
for me it worked.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac ,

1. Close the Eclipse Workspace
2. Go to /Users/username/.subversion/auth/svn.simple
3. Delete. The file inside it with  encrypted(Big Alpha Numeric) file name.
4. Open key chain(/Applications/Utilities/) and delete the key saved for SVN.
5. Now open Eclipse workspace try to update your project , prompt will show up asking you the SVN credentials
6. Give you updated SVN credentials and update it In keychain
   .

Answer (score 0):

I'm using svn+ssh protocol to access SVN. 
What I had to do to fix a similar issue, was to open Putty and reconfigure it so that it did not have wrong_user_name@myserver but correct_user_name@myserver in the saved sessions.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse: Ctrl + F8 -> SVN Repository Exploring -> Right Click in the respository -> Location Properties -> Finish ;)

Answer (score 0):

I deleted file inside `svn.simple` directory at below path on windows machine (Windows 7):

```
C:\Users\[user_name]\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth
```

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

There are several places on Windows where SVN will place cached credentials depending on system configuration. Read [SVNBook | Client Credentials](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.netmodel.html#svn.serverconfig.netmodel.creds).

- The main credential store is located in **`%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth`** and you can run [**`svn auth`**](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.9.html#svn-auth) command to view and manage its contents.
- You can also run [**`cmdkey`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754243) to view the credentials stored in Windows Credential Manager.
- If your SVN server is integrated with Active Directory and supports Integrated Windows Authentication such as VisualSVN Server, your Windows logon credentials are used for authentication, but they are not cached. You can run [**`whoami`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771299) to find out your user account name.

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching answer for the same, but none of above didn't work  for me.But I did the following steps and got rectified.

My scenario:-

1. Eclipse installed on linux
2. Eclipse version: 2019.03
3. Previously I selected, store Password locally ( so whenever any updates from existing svn repository , not prompting for password).

Solution:-
Remove locally stored credentials.

Steps :

1. In linux allow show hidden files ( Open File Explorer , Click On "View" and click on "Show Hidden Files"
2. Go to User Home Folder-> .eclipse/.org.eclipse.equinox.security/
3. Open & Edit "secure_storage" file any text edit and remove all the contents & save . ( Better to take backup of "secure_storage" file before editing)

Now will ask while connecting SVN

Thank You