# How to change credentials for Hg repository in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, mercurial

This is exactly the same case as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914895/how-to-change-credentials-for-svn-repository-in-eclipse) one, but with Hg instead of SVN. I have MercurialEclipse installed, and I have changed the password of my remote repo. Now when I synch it fails.

I have not found any conf file in "C:\Documents and Settings\%USER%\Application Data..." about Hg.
I have deleted the .keyring eclipse file and restarted but still fails.

Eclipse 3.6.1 with MercurialEclipse1.6, on windows Vista

---

In reply to pyfunc (thanks):

I found an entry like this in .hg\hgrc:
[paths]
default = https://user:oldpassword@bitbucket.org/myprojectpath

so I changed to the new password and restarted eclipse, but still I get 'authorization failed'...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found out a way to achieve this. If I select "Synchronize With" I get a dialog and I am able to insert the good values, so now I could synch!

This does not explain why changing values in .hgrc didn't work, but at least is solved now, although it would be nice to find out about the details...

Answer (score 0):

Typically that is stored in .hgrc file. That is the user configuration file stores in the HOME directory. You should be able to change the password there.

As per the man page of Mercurial, there are some suggestions about the location of config file on windows.

```
 1. <install-dir>\Mercurial.ini
 2. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mercurial
 3. C:\Mercurial\Mercurial.ini
 4. %HOME%\Mercurial.ini or 
 5. %HOME%\.hgrc or 
 6. %USERPROFILE%\Mercurial.ini or
 7. %USERPROFILE%\.hgrc
```

it could also lie in /.hg/hgrc

Comment: replied in the question as I needed more space than I have here, thanks. Also Roger Pate was right about the location, but not sure why it's not working yet...

Comment: @raticulin: Delete the .hgrc and this will force the plugin to ask for those information.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the config file after some digging... it's in ${workspace_location}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse

If you close Eclipse, open this file, and delete just the lines at the bottom starting with repo_, the settings you have saved for that repository (including credentials) should be cleared the next time you open Eclipse. You'll probably want to make a backup of the file just in case.

Since these credentials override whatever you have in your hgrc, deleting these should allow the repositories to authenticate with your global settings. You won't necessarily see the credentials in the username/password fields in Eclipse, but if you click Next/Finish anyway, it should work fine.