# Invalid SVN credentials eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

Ever since my svn password was changed I couldn't make it work in Subclipse. After deleting my keyring in my home (I'm on Ubuntu) I can update and commit in the console without a problem, but in Eclipse it always asks me my credentials, and when I give them I get this error :

```
org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: Negotiate authentication failed: 'No valid credentials provided'
```

How can my credentials be valid in the console but not in Eclipse? Can I clean it or something?

What I tried:

- Reimporting the projects after deleting them with metadata
- Deleting the keyring in the home
- Deleting and reinstalling the plugin
- Switching to SVNKit

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change credentials for SVN repository in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914895/how-to-change-credentials-for-svn-repository-in-eclipse)

Comment: I've tried most of the solutions there (except that "location properties" thing that I couldn't find in the SVN repository perspective) and it didn't help. I think my case is more of a bug, while the question was how to change credentials in a regular case.

Comment: The error kind of implies your repository might be using Kerberos (Negotiate) authentication.  Does the SVN command line work?  For example, svn up or svn ls.  Something that has to authenticate.

Comment: Yes as I mentioned in the OP the command line accepts my credentials, I can update, commit... That's how I'm currently functioning, but it's not nearly as practical for stuff like history or compares.