# Eclipse lunar subclipse windows 8.1 removing svn user credentials

Tags: eclipse, svn

Added a user account to subsclipse in Lunar but even after I removing the credentials form security tab and restart the same repository credential work inside. Is there any hidden files to be removed or some other settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> JavaHL caches the information in the same location as the command line
>   client -- in the Subversion runtime configuration area. On Windows
>   this is located in %APPDATA%\Subversion\auth. On Linux and OSX it is
>   located in ~/.subversion/auth. Just find and delete the file with the
>   cached information.

Please Refer [How to change credentials for SVN repository in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914895/how-to-change-credentials-for-svn-repository-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following in eclipse:

```
Open SVN Repositories View
Open Location Properties
Show Credentials For: press [X] button
Select user, write password, press [Finish]
```